# Default ctor not generated when there's a template copy ctor

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
template<class T>
class MyClass {
 public:
  //MyClass() = default;

 template<class X>
 MyClass(MyClass<X>& other)
 {
  val = other.getVal();
 }

 T getVal()
 {
  return val;
 }

 private:
  T val;
};

main()
{
 MyClass<double> xd;       //this one causing the problem
 MyClass<double> xd1(xd);  //this one is fine

 MyClass<int> xi(xd);
}
```

This code will not compile.
But if you uncomment MyClass() = default, then everything is fine.
As far as I remember the **template ctor not preventing compiler from generating the default ctor and copy ctor as well**. 
And indeed the compiler complaining only when trying to create object through the default ctor, but not for copy construction (which in this case is compiler generated)
The code was compiled with g++ 5.4.0 and 7.1.0. Same behavior with both

Comment: [This default constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) might interest you. Especially the sections about the [implicitly declared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Implicitly-declared_default_constructor), the [implicitly defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Implicitly-defined_default_constructor), and of course the [implicitly *deleted*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Deleted_implicitly-declared_default_constructor) default constructors.

Comment: `MyClass(MyClass<X>& other)` is **not** a copy constructor.

Comment: Folks, yet again, I didn't mention even once that template ctor is a copy ctor. Thus I'm quite puzzled how you've concluded that this was my question. According to N.Jossutis and S.Myers, not template ctor might prevent compiler from implicitly generating default and copy ctor. That what I was trying to say

Comment: I guess the compiler is interpreting the mere availability of the non-copy constructor as being enough to delete the default constructor. Why would it be any more complicated than that?

Answer (score 7):

This is not a copy constructor:

```
template<class X>
MyClass(MyClass<X>& other) {
    val = other.getVal();
}
```

This is a constructor taking a mutable lvalue reference to many different type than this class.

This is a copy constructor:

```
MyClass(const MyClass&) {
    // ...
}
```

You can test if a function bus a special function by trying to put `= default` after it's signature. If the compiler complains about your misuse of defaulted functions, you function is not a special one.

When any other constructor than special constructors is added, the default constructor is not generated. That function being a template makes no different effect than a non template one. In that case, `MyClass() = default` is indeed required.

From cppreference:

> If no user-declared constructors of any kind are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare a default constructor as an inline public member of its class.

On the contrary, if a user provided constructor is declared, no implicitly defined default constructor is defined.

And from `[class.ctor]§5`:

> A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X that can be called without an argument. If there is no user-declared constructor for class X, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted (8.4).

Since your class has a user provided constructor, no implicitly declared/defined constructor is generated. Again, you can always force it's generation with `= default`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my question was not put this way. I didn't said that template ctor is a copy ctor. But rather that no template ctor might prevent a compiler from generating a default ctor and copy ctor. Thus a behavior I've seen was quite strange

Comment: @Uris Just as I said it the end of the question, *any* constructor that is not a special constructor prohibit the generation of the default constructor, whether it's a template or not.

Comment: @Uris I clarified the last paragraph. Tell me of there's anything else.

Comment: @Uris I also added a quite from cppreference.